# Change Expanded Titled Pane Background in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have an accordion with few titled pane. I want to change the background color of the titled pane when expanded. The default color seems to be white. How do I change it to black?

[image]

I've tried this css but it does not work.

```
.titled-pane > *.content {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-border-color: black;
}
```

Comment: Create and post a [mre] that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.titled-pane > .title {  
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
    -fx-background-insets: 0; 
}

.titled-pane > .title > *.text {
    -fx-fill: #fff;
}

.titled-pane > .content {
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. It changes the title background but the content background is still white.

Comment: @DinesG Are you sure that your content doesn't have its own styles?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I made it work by adding a scroll pane under the titled-pane, expanded it to fill height and changed the background color for the scroll pane.